# Coffee pod producers in europe?

Tags: pods

How many coffee pod producers are in Europe?

And how many coffee producers that does not provide pods?

Comment: 50 countries, 10 million square kilometers. Do you really think we can list all coffee producers? And where do we draw the line - just those that run farms (somewhere on the world), import, roast...? For the pods, I also think this varies, outside the protected brands there are many that make paper filter pods for the senseo system. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-serve_coffee_container